# How do I authenticate against GitHub using an API key?

Tags: javascript, authentication, github, github-api, api-key

I am trying to use the [GitHub Javascript API](https://github.com/github-tools/github) but am unable to authenticate using my API key. The [API Docs](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.1.0/index.html) say I can use:

```
{
  username: 'my-username',
  password: 'my-password'
  // , token: 'or an optional oAuth token'
}
```

But I'd like to use my API Key instead, much like I can do with `curl` from the command line. (for example)

```
curl --user "$user:$api_key" --include --request DELETE "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/labels/enhancement"
```

I've tried using my API Key as the `token` but that doesn't work.

Is use of the API Key to access GitHub via the Github API wrapper not supported?  That would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it turns out what I was calling my API Key is the same thing as the [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and I was just being confused because

```
import GitHub from 'github-api'

const gh = new GitHub({
    token: 'MY-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN-OBTAINED-FROM-github.com/settings/tokens' // real token redacted obviously
})

const me = gh.getUser()
console.log('me', me)
```

was spitting out

```
me User {
  __apiBase: 'https://api.github.com',
  __auth: 
   { token: '970818535b841883ff2735fe127d289032970389',
     username: undefined,
     password: undefined },
  __AcceptHeader: 'v3',
  __authorizationHeader: 'token MY-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN-OBTAINED-FROM-github.com/settings/tokens',
  __user: undefined }
```

and I was interpreting `__user: undefined` to mean that the authentication was not working.

However if I actually try then adding

```
me.listNotifications().then(
    notifications => console.log('notifications', notifications),
    err => console.log('error', err)
).catch(err => console.log('fatal', err))
```

tadah it works.

If I throw in a rubbish token `new GitHub` doesn't complain (because presumably it's not actually going off to GitHub to do the auth at that point as I first thought), but the `.listNotifications()` does get rejected with a `401` error.

So, that's resolved my confusion.